# Replace all the spaces in a file’s name with an underscore during the upload process

Tags: php

I have a file named upload_file.php which uploads an image file to my web server. The problem I am having is that I want to replace all the spaces in the file’s name with an underscore during the upload process. I know this could be done using str_replace(), but I have no idea where I should use str_replace() within my code. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the full code contained within my upload_file.php file:

```
<?php
require_once '../../config.php';
include '../secure.php';
if ($login_status != 1) exit();
if (isset($_GET['done'])) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else {
        if ($_POST['type'] == 'wallpaper') {
            $directory = "../../files/";
        }
        else {
            $directory = "../../files/images/"; 
        }

        $filename = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
        $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

        if (file_exists($directory . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            echo htmlspecialchars($_FILES["file"]["name"]) . " already exists. ";
        }
        elseif (((strpos($ext, "php") !== false) || $ext == 'aspx' || $ext == 'py' || $ext == 'htaccess') && !isset($allow_php_uploads)) {
            echo 'Uploading PHP files disabled (<a target="_blank" href=""></a>)';
        }
        else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $directory . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            header("Location: upload-complete.php?type=".htmlspecialchars($_POST['type'])."&newfile=". htmlspecialchars($_FILES["file"]["name"])."&id=".intval($_POST['id'])."");
        }
    }
} else { ?>

<head>
 <style type="text/css">
 body {
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
 }
 </style>
 </head>

 <form action="upload_file.php?done=1" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="max-width:230px;" />
  <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo intval($_GET['id']);?>" />
  <input name="type" type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['type']);?>" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a variable that holds the name of the file and replace all spaces there. Then in the rest of the code, replace `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` by that variable.

```
<?php
require_once '../../config.php';
include '../secure.php';
if ($login_status != 1) exit();
if (isset($_GET['done'])) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else {
        if ($_POST['type'] == 'wallpaper') {
            $directory = "../../files/";
        }
        else {
            $directory = "../../files/images/"; 
        }

        $filename = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
        $file = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $_FILES['file']['name']);    // <-- Replace spaces
        $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

        if (file_exists($directory . $file)) {
            echo htmlspecialchars($file) . " already exists. ";
        }
        elseif (((strpos($ext, "php") !== false) || $ext == 'aspx' || $ext == 'py' || $ext == 'htaccess') && !isset($allow_php_uploads)) {
            echo 'Uploading PHP files disabled (<a target="_blank" href=""></a>)';
        }
        else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $directory . $file);
            header("Location: upload-complete.php?type=".htmlspecialchars($_POST['type'])."&newfile=". htmlspecialchars($file)."&id=".intval($_POST['id'])."");
        }
    }
} else { ?>

<head>
 <style type="text/css">
 body {
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
 }
 </style>
 </head>

 <form action="upload_file.php?done=1" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="max-width:230px;" />
  <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo intval($_GET['id']);?>" />
  <input name="type" type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['type']);?>" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Your code works perfectly. Thank you. Although I did change the following code: $file = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $_FILES['file']['name']); to: $file = str_replace(" ", "_", $_FILES['file']['name']);

Comment: I just noticed in my first reply to you that in both codes I typed the underscore between the single quotation marks and double quotation marks is automatically removed by stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try replace the spaces with underscores by having a whitelist and the replace function. So you can do something like:

```
$file = preg_replace("/[^-_a-z0-9]+/i", "_", $file);
```

I can't test it right now but something like that should work fine. Basically, it replaces the characters that they are not in the whitelist of the "[^-_a-z0-9]+/i".